think "it" silly vs. think (that) "it's/it is/it was" silly
As a native American English speaker, I would only ever use the second one. The first one, though, is something that I have seen (not so much heard) a lot from native speakers in both formal and informal contexts. Is there a name for the grammatical structure in the first one, and is it correlated to age/gender/region/social class/any other demographic information?

Same meaning, different grammar. "I think it silly" is a single clause with "it" as direct object and "strange" as objective complement. By contrast, in "I think (that) it is silly", there are two clauses: the matrix clause (the whole sentence) and the subordinate clause "(that) it is silly" functioning as complement of "think". Some people call "it silly" in the first example a verbless clause (or 'small clause').

I'm not aware of it being related to any regional or other dialect.
